# How do I set the drop pin to focus on the center of map?

Tags: leaflet, geocoding

I been trying to find a way on how I can set the drop pin to focus on the center of map or have the map to adjust to focus the drop pin at the center. As you can see from the image below, the drop pin is shown at the upper left corner of screen. Below is a snippet of code I'm currently working on.

I'm currently using [leaftlet.js](https://leafletjs.com/) to provide the interactive map

[image]

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

    var map = L.map('mapid').setView([14.5906216, 120.9799696], 12);

    L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
        attribution: '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
    }).addTo(map);

    let geocoder = new L.Control.Geocoder.Nominatim();
    var location = $('.location').text();

    geocoder.geocode(location, function(results) {    
        var latLng = new L.LatLng(results[0].center.lat, results[0].center.lng);
        var marker = new L.Marker (latLng);
  

        var geocodeLocation = Object.values(latLng);
        // console.log(geocodeLocation);

        L.marker(geocodeLocation).addTo(map)
        .bindPopup('A pretty CSS3 popup.<br> Easily customizable.')
        .openPopup()



    });
})
```

```html
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.5.1/dist/leaflet.css"
    integrity="sha512-xwE/Az9zrjBIphAcBb3F6JVqxf46+CDLwfLMHloNu6KEQCAWi6HcDUbeOfBIptF7tcCzusKFjFw2yuvEpDL9wQ=="
    crossorigin=""/>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.5.1/dist/leaflet.js"
    integrity="sha512-GffPMF3RvMeYyc1LWMHtK8EbPv0iNZ8/oTtHPx9/cc2ILxQ+u905qIwdpULaqDkyBKgOaB57QTMg7ztg8Jm2Og=="
    crossorigin=""></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/perliedman-leaflet-control-geocoder/1.9.0/Control.Geocoder.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>


<body>
    <div id="mapid"></div>

    <span class="location">New York</span>

</body>
```

Comment: map.setView(new L.LatLng(latitude,longitude),zoom); or map.panTo(new L.LatLng(lagps, logps)); or use the center[] parameter when you create the map.

Comment: The only problem here is that it won't accept values wrap around an array

Comment: Don't understand the problem. As you have the GPS of the point, just use the Lat and Long in the center[] parameter when you create the map. Same way you set the zoom.